# Parse CONNECT requests using Akka-http

Tags: java, http, proxy, akka, akka-http

Is there a way to make an HTTP CONNECT request in akka?

I am trying to write a proxy app in akka and I am getting this error for every request that I am making:

> 16:10:19.179 [default-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-7] WARN akka.actor.ActorSystemImpl - Illegal request, responding with status '400 Bad Request': CONNECT requests are not supported: Rejectin
> g CONNECT request to 'doc.akka.io:443'

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried matching the incoming HttpRequest's `method` with [CONNECT](https://doc.akka.io/api/akka-http/current/akka/http/scaladsl/model/HttpMethods$.html#CONNECT:akka.http.scaladsl.model.HttpMethod)